# How to test amazon boto email service used in django?

Tags: automated-testing, unit-tests, whitebox-testing

In my Django application, I am using the Amazon boto email service for sending messages to my clients. I am doing the testing of view function which will send the email.

Now I am getting confused about how to test the boto service. How to set up a virtual email inbox to get test the email service. Or should I test the boto service?

Answer (score 2):

One of the common ways to unit test the code that uses `boto` client, aside from "manual" mocking and patching, is to use the [`moto` library](https://github.com/spulec/moto) which provides a drop-in replacement for the `boto` client specifically for the use in testing.

I don't think you need to set up a virtual inbox, just check that the notification was sent with `moto`.